# Automatically create virtual email for user using postfix

Tags: email, postfix

On our website, we have some special users that can be contacted by email.
It means that for now, they have a public profile page where after a mouse click their email is visible.
Moreover, to log on our website, you must provide an email adress as username and a password.
Which mean that by displaying some users' email adress, we're displaying the username needed to log into their account.

So, mostly for security reason, we want to add the following line into postfix virtual_alias_map :

```
someuser@our-domain.com   user_real_email@gmail.com
```

This way, only someuser@our-domain.com is displayed on our website and it also solve the problem of users with multiple email.

Problem is, we already have multiple lines into our virtual_alias_maps file and we would like not to mix manually added lines with automatically added ones.

So, is using the virtual_alias_maps file the best solution ? Can't we have two separeted files and include them both (like in most configuration files) ? Is there another solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have more than one entry in your [`virtual_alias_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps). They can even be of different [types](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types).

> Specify zero or more "type:name" lookup tables, separated by whitespace or comma. Tables will be searched in the specified order until a match is found. Note: these lookups are recursive.